# Could not build module 'React'

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am stuck with this error **Could not build module 'React'** while trying to integrate react native to an existing iOS project. Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: Is your Cocoapods setup working?

Comment: We'd need to see more to know for sure. What platform are you targeting? What platform are you building for? What SDK are you compiling with? What's the verbose error message?

Comment: @PæturMagnussen, Yes cocoapod setup is fine.

Comment: @vsanthanam510, as mentioned above i am integrating react native to an existing iOS project and i am getting this error inside the code of one of the pod dependancy

Comment: Which version of React Native are you using?

Comment: @Kishoretheju you didn't answer my question. You should look up the terms 'SDK' and 'Platform' mean with respect to iOS development. What version of the iOS SDK are you compiling with. What version/platform are you targeting. What's the verbose error message. Your screenshot alone is not enough to debug -- there are a lot of reasons why a module might fail to build -- duplicate symbols, missing symbols, incorrectly formatted or missing `.modulemap`, etc.

Comment: I know that @vsanthanam510, as far as i remember there was no verbose error in that case, base SDK was iOS 11.2 and target was iOS 9 and platform iOS, XCode 9.2 and react native version 0.55.3. Was able to find the issue, have posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to solve this issue, issue was because of incorrect path to a script file Pods-resources.sh that was used in a run script by cocoapod in my project.

This is the run script i am referring to,
[image]

And after making necessary changes for integration of react native, Pods folder in the path "${SRCROOT}/Pods/Target Support Files/**Pods**/Pods-resources.sh" was missing and Pods-resources.sh file was instead present in the folder Pods-MyProjectName ie at path "${SRCROOT}/Pods/Target Support Files/**Pods-MyProjectName**/Pods-resources.sh", so replacing old path with new path solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Incase this happens to anyone else. This can also occur if you accidentally create a C File instead of an Objective C implementation file.